# Load QML source from string

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Normally we set up a Qt application in this way:

```cpp
QGuiApplication qtapp(argc, argv);
QQuickView rootView;
rootView.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
rootView.setSource(QUrl("qrc:myfile.qml"));
rootView.show();

QQmlEngine * qmlEngine = view.engine();
QQmlComponent component(qmlEngine, QUrl("qrc:myview.qml"));
QQuickItem *  qItem = qobject_cast<QQuickItem *>(component.create());
```

However, we would like to get rid of the external `qml` files and pass the source code directly. This is possible for the `QQuickItem` in this way:

```cpp
QQmlEngine * qmlEngine = view.engine();
QQmlComponent component(qmlEngine);
component.setData("my source code here", QUrl());
QQuickItem *  qItem = qobject_cast<QQuickItem *>(component.create());
```

However, we have not been able to do the same for the `rootView`. How can we do that?

Comment: You know you can embed the QML files in your application as resources and then load the embedded resource, right?

Comment: You can construct `QUrl`s for local file paths,  so dump your string to a temporary file and reference that?

Comment: Another interesting solution would be to use a QNetworkAccessManager, the name suggest the data should come from the network, but you can implement it however you like

Comment: @Amfasis I tried that previously, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733670/dynamically-loading-qml-from-memory-instead-of-a-url,  but it was way more complicated. I might go back to that approach if nothing easier turns up.

Comment: yes, it depends a bit on the situation. Could you clarify where the sources should come from?

Comment: Errr... who is *we*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `QQuickView` doesn't have this functionality, but `QQmlComponent` has it and as the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qquickview.html#details) about `QQuickView` states

> This is a convenience subclass of QQuickWindow which will
> automatically load and display a QML scene when given the URL of the
> main source file. Alternatively, you can instantiate your own objects
> using QQmlComponent and place them in a manually setup QQuickWindow.

So it might be possible by using `QQmlComponent` in combination with `QQuickWindow` instead of the `QQuickView`. Something like this of course with your way of setting the QML source in between:

```
QQmlEngine engine;
QQmlComponent component(&engine);
QObject* obj = component.create();
QQuickWindow* win = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(obj);
```

I got the source from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/bennofs/fe06b7b49b564e70de3d) when I searched for `QQuickWindow` used with `QQmlComponent`.

Comment: This works as intended and answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question title indicates how to load QML from string, whereas your question body says how to load QML from URL. Let's answer both:

Answer 1: Loading QML from C++ string

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("sourcecode","source code");
```

Then, have a mini QML source code compiler in your app like this:

```
Page {
    id: page
    anchors.fill: parent
    property var obj: null
    function compile(code, filePath) {
        if (obj) { obj.destroy(); obj = null; }
        if (!code) { return; }
        obj = Qt.createQmlObject(code, page, filePath ?? "dynamic");
        obj.width = Qt.binding( () => page.width );
        obj.height = Qt.binding( () => page.height );
    }
    Component.onCompleted: compile(sourcecode)
}
```

Answer 2: Load QML from C++ URL

This is similar to the above:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("sourceurl","source code url");
```

Then in QML have a loader, e.g.

```
Page {
    id: page
    Loader {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: sourceurl
    }
}
```